# Increase height of Sankey Highcharts data series bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, sankey-diagram

Using Sankey chart of highcharts, I need to know if it's possible to increase the height of the bar that is associated with each of the data, and also to show additional information in the tooltip for each of the series data in a new line.

I tried to used css to increase the height of the bars but it didn't work out

https://jsfiddle.net/samwhite/9a5qymvs/

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
        colors: ['#538FB3', '#F6F6BC', '#96CAC1', '#C1BED6', '#EA8E83', '#8AAFC9', '#EAB375', '#AFCF78', '#F6D3E5', '#2f6f81', '#D9D9D9', '#3D6D52'],
      })
      Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: { //height: 600,
          //width: 2000, 
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Sankey',
          align: 'left',
          style: {
            color: '#2B2B2B',
            fontSize: '20px',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          }
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        accessibility: {
          point: {
            valueDescriptionFormat: '{index}. {point.from} to {point.to}, {point.weight}.'
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          formatter: function() {
            let weight = this.point.weight,
              from = this.point.from,
              to = this.point.to,
              displayedWeight;
            weight === 1 ? displayedWeight = 0 : displayedWeight = weight;

            return 'From <b>' + from +
              '</b> to <b>' + to + '</b> weight is ' + displayedWeight;
          }
        },
        series: [{
          keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
          data: [
            [' Accelerated Filer 2017', ' Non-accelerated Filer 2018', 79],
            [' Accelerated Filer 2017', ' Smaller Reporting Accelerated Filer 2018', 23],
            [' Accelerated Filer 2017', ' Smaller Reporting Company 2018', 34],
            [' Large Accelerated Filer 2017', ' Accelerated Filer 2018', 61],
            [' Large Accelerated Filer 2017', ' Non-accelerated Filer 2018', 14],
            [' Non-accelerated Filer 2017', ' Accelerated Filer 2018', 222],
            [' Non-accelerated Filer 2017', ' Large Accelerated Filer 2018', 65],
            [' Non-accelerated Filer 2017', ' Smaller Reporting Accelerated Filer 2018', 1],
            [' Non-accelerated Filer 2017', ' Smaller Reporting Company 2018', 45],
            [' Smaller Reporting Accelerated Filer 2017', ' Accelerated Filer 2018', 20],
            [' Smaller Reporting Accelerated Filer 2017', ' Non-accelerated Filer 2018', 5],
            [' Smaller Reporting Accelerated Filer 2017', ' Smaller Reporting Company 2018', 3],
            [' Smaller Reporting Company 2017', ' Accelerated Filer 2018', 61],
            [' Smaller Reporting Company 2017', ' Large Accelerated Filer 2018', 1],
            [' Smaller Reporting Company 2017', ' Non-accelerated Filer 2018', 2039],
            [' Smaller Reporting Company 2017', ' Smaller Reporting Accelerated Filer 2018', 6],
            [' Smaller Reporting Company 2017', ' Status Indeterminate 2018', 1],
            [' Status Indeterminate 2017', ' Non-accelerated Filer 2018', 1],
            [' Accelerated Filer 2018', ' Large Accelerated Filer 2019', 87],
            [' Accelerated Filer 2018', ' Non-accelerated Filer 2019', 130],
            [' Accelerated Filer 2018', ' Smaller Reporting Accelerated Filer 2019', 5],
            [' Accelerated Filer 2018', ' Smaller Reporting Company 2019', 6],
            [' Large Accelerated Filer 2018', ' Accelerated Filer 2019', 86],
            [' Large Accelerated Filer 2018', ' Non-accelerated Filer 2019', 12],
            [' Non-accelerated Filer 2018', ' Accelerated Filer 2019', 230],
            [' Non-accelerated Filer 2018', ' Large Accelerated Filer 2019', 72],
            [' Non-accelerated Filer 2018', ' Smaller Reporting Company 2019', 19],
            [' Smaller Reporting Accelerated Filer 2018', ' Accelerated Filer 2019', 18],
            [' Smaller Reporting Accelerated Filer 2018', ' Smaller Reporting Company 2019', 1],
            [' Smaller Reporting Company 2018', ' Accelerated Filer 2019', 10],
            [' Smaller Reporting Company 2018', ' Non-accelerated Filer 2019', 150],
            [' Smaller Reporting Company 2018', ' Smaller Reporting Accelerated Filer 2019', 2],
            [' Smaller Reporting Company 2018', ' Status Indeterminate 2019', 1],
            [' Status Indeterminate 2018', ' Large Accelerated Filer 2019', 1],
            [' Status Indeterminate 2018', ' Non-accelerated Filer 2019', 5],
            [' Status Indeterminate 2018', ' Smaller Reporting Company 2019', 1],
            [' Accelerated Filer 2019', ' Large Accelerated Filer 2020', 84],
            [' Accelerated Filer 2019', ' Non-accelerated Filer 2020', 530],
            [' Accelerated Filer 2019', ' Status Indeterminate 2020', 8],
            [' Large Accelerated Filer 2019', ' Accelerated Filer 2020', 167],
            [' Large Accelerated Filer 2019', ' Non-accelerated Filer 2020', 16],
            [' Large Accelerated Filer 2019', ' Status Indeterminate 2020', 4],
            [' Non-accelerated Filer 2019', ' Accelerated Filer 2020', 99],
            [' Non-accelerated Filer 2019', ' Large Accelerated Filer 2020', 64],
            [' Non-accelerated Filer 2019', ' Smaller Reporting Company 2020', 1],
            [' Non-accelerated Filer 2019', ' Status Indeterminate 2020', 2],
            [' Smaller Reporting Accelerated Filer 2019', ' Smaller Reporting Company 2020', 1],
            [' Smaller Reporting Company 2019', ' Accelerated Filer 2020', 1],
            [' Smaller Reporting Company 2019', ' Non-accelerated Filer 2020', 33],
            [' Smaller Reporting Company 2019', ' Status Indeterminate 2020', 2],
            [' Status Indeterminate 2019', ' Large Accelerated Filer 2020', 2],
            [' Status Indeterminate 2019', ' Non-accelerated Filer 2020', 1],
            [' Accelerated Filer 2020', ' Large Accelerated Filer 2021', 17],
            [' Accelerated Filer 2020', ' Non-accelerated Filer 2021', 29],
            [' Large Accelerated Filer 2020', ' Accelerated Filer 2021', 16],
            [' Non-accelerated Filer 2020', ' Accelerated Filer 2021', 15],
            [' Non-accelerated Filer 2020', ' Large Accelerated Filer 2021', 12],
            [' Smaller Reporting Company 2020', ' Non-accelerated Filer 2021', 7],
            [' Status Indeterminate 2020', ' Accelerated Filer 2021', 1],
            [' Status Indeterminate 2020', ' Non-accelerated Filer 2021', 1]
          ],
          type: 'sankey',
          dataLabels: {
            format: '<span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 16px">' +
              '{point.fromNode.name} \u2192 {point.toNode.name}: {point.weight}' +
              '</span>',
            nodeFormat: '{point.name}'
          },
          name: 'Sankey demo series'
        }]
      });
```

Comment: To add a new line in the tooltip you can use the HTML break tag. About the height of the bars - I am not sure what do you want to achieve, because each height is calculated base on the data value, customizing it might disturb the chart readability.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel thanks for your message. Can you also tell me if I can apply different colors to each of the category that I have on the chart? For example, I need a different color for each of the smaller companies, and a different color for the companies that are non-accelerated.

Comment: You can define the color for each node, take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fs5ga0q9/
API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.nodes.color

Comment: @SebastianWędzel thank you for sharing that link. That helps a lot.